# How to build a linear regression model with one independent variable and three dependent variables in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have one independent variable `x` and three dependent variables `y1`, `y2`, and `y3`. I wonder how I can build a linear regression model in R? Thanks for any help.

[image]

Sorry for the confusing expression. `y1`, `y2`, and `y3` are dependent variables and I only need one straight line to build the linear relationship. The final solution should be like this:

[image]

```
set.seed(88)
x = sample(x=(-3:3), size = 20, replace = T)

y1= sample(x=(5:10), size = 20, replace = T)
y2= sample(x=(10:15), size = 20, replace = T)
y3= sample(x=(5:15), size = 20, replace = T)

plot(x,y1, ylim = c(5,15))
points(x,y2, col="red")
points(x,y3, col="blue")
```

Comment: are you sure you are not confusing dependent and independent variables? you can regress x over y1, y2, y3, but the other way around you should be talking about three regressions y1 = f1(x), y2 =g(x) and y3=h(x)

Comment: You're looking for a `multivariate regression`. Check out the vignette with the `rrr` package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrr/vignettes/rrr.html

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Thanks, but I y1, y2, and y3 are dependent variables, and I need only one straight line to build the linear relationship.

Comment: sorry, but you have to think it over again - there is no 'one single line'. if you think of (y1, y2, y3) resulting vector, you cannot regress it over (x), even if you call it multivariate.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Thanks and I have re-edited the question.

Comment: What are the variables on the x and y axis of that second graph?

Comment: I think the issue might be that you actually only have one independent variable, y and not 3 different ones. In that case you can do x1 = rep(x,3), y4 = c(y1,y2,y3), model = lm(y4 ~ x1)

Comment: based on a graph you seem to assemble a new variable y, which consists of y1, y2 and y3 and regress it over x. this is still a univariate regression

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Thanks, could you formally answer the question and maybe plot the result?

Comment: @Luis You are amazing and I believe your answer is correct. Could you provide more details so I can accept your answer?

Comment: No problem, edited my answer below accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lm is function you're looking for, though first you've got to bundle all your y varibles into a single one, with their respective x variables

```
> y4 = c(y1,y2,y3)
> x1 = rep(x,3)
> 
> model = lm(y4 ~ x1)
> 
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y4 ~ x1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9174 -1.1715  0.0799  2.0743  5.0771 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  9.917363   0.296917   33.40   <2e-16 ***
x1          -0.002786   0.139197   -0.02    0.984    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.284 on 58 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  6.904e-06, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01723 
F-statistic: 0.0004005 on 1 and 58 DF,  p-value: 0.9841
```

Answer (score 2):

A regression on multiple dependent variable is called a multivariate regression, common in some disciplines and very uncommon in others. A simple linear model could be obtained in base R through:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, y3)  #bind your observations into a dataframe
lm(cbind(y1,y2,y3) ~ x, data = df) #run an linear fit
```

Be aware that there is considerable debate among statistians regarding the best implementations of a multivariate regression. For further details, go here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/multivariate-multiple-regression-in-r

Comment: Thanks, but I need only one straight line to build the linear relationship.

Comment: what are the disciplines where multivariate regression is uncommon?

Comment: I can speak of Political Science and International Relations, where I was taugt in my undergrad that it was a mistake/impossible to operationalize more than one dependent variable.
I recently attended a PhD dissertation proposal defense where one of the referees mistakenly criticised the proposal because it ran a multivariate regression. When I corrected the referee, he answered that he had never seen one multivariate regression before and that he genuinely believed it was a mistake.

Comment: I would say using multivariate regression more depends on if you are in a data-rich environment and if your care more about regression fit or structure (eg in economics a VAR, "vector autoregression", can give you a nice fit, but the coefficients would be atheoretic, uninterpretable). I can see that in political science you would want something more easily interprtable, but once there is more data coming to the field (eg from social net behavious analysis), slightly more sophisticated methods would be more common too, I think.

Comment: I agree with you 100%.